# Why i can't install software from Ubuntu Snapcraft or Ubuntu software center in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: software-installation, network-manager, snap, settings, snap-store

I use Ubuntu 20. But i can't find softwares to install and shows a pop-up like this -
How to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  Are you sure your system isn't a 20.04 or other *deb* based release? as there is no GUI on any *snap* only 20 product (eg. Ubuntu Core 20).  Ubuntu has both *year.month* products, and since 2016 *year* products (which are *snap* only intended for *headless* operation on devices, appliances & within the cloud).

Comment: Do you know for certain if your connection is metered or not?  If you know that it is not metered, then edit your network connection and in the General tab set the Metered connection to No.

Answer (score 0):

Open WIFI settings and click on the settings icon of the network you are connected to and un-check the metered connection option. it will solve the popup issue. And it is possible that you will be on 20.04 or 20.10 as there is no Ubuntu 20. Ubuntu versions are year.month.